# Linux CVLC SSH - display on remote computer's monitor

Tags: linux, ssh, multiple-monitors, vlc-media-player

Is their any way to launch VLC on a remote computer using the command line via an SSH session and display the video to the remote computer's monitor?
I don't want to tunnel the video back, I want to remote to a computer using SSH and run VLC to play on the computers monitor without using VNC/RDP.
Is there a VLC parameter I'm missing?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the parameter I was missing:

```
DISPLAY=:0 vlc cam.sdp
```

Adding DISPLAY=:0 opened VLC on the remote computers monitor rather than it trying to open it in the terminal.

Comment: this will play the movie inside the very console itself. Charming, but no use

Comment: Try `DISPLAY=localhost:0` instead of `DISPLAY=:0`. That has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. open a console on your local computer
2. ssh to the remote computer
3. do `export DISPLAY=:0`[ENTER]
4. play the movie on the remote computer monitor with `vlc -f MyMovie.mkw`
5. Have fun!

Note: -f option will play full screen. More options with  `vlc --help`

Answer (score -1):

use real vnc for remote your linux

https://www.realvnc.com/en/

Try using

https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/docs/debian-install-remove.html

what are you using ubunto or centos

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I want to initialize VLC from an SSH session, without using VNC or RDP.